# iPhone - App crashes when trying to save new objects after deleting objects in CoreData

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

Okay, I'm having a problem saving after I've deleted all the objects I have stored in CoreData. I have no problem with saving if I don't delete anything, but as soon as I ask it to delete all the objects (everything deletes with no errors or problems), and then try saving again, it crashes and just gives me a **program received signal: SIGABRT**. Here's my code.

```
- (void)deleteStoredData
{
    // Define our table/entity to use  
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:MOVIE_LIST inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    // Setup the fetch request  
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // Fetch the records and handle an error  
    NSError *error;
    NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
            NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [self.listOfMovies objectAtIndex:i];
            [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];
        }
    }

    [request release];
}
```

I thought it might be me comparing self.listOfMovies to the objects stored, so I did a fresh fetch, copied it to a temp NSMutableArray, then replaced self.listOfMovies with temp.  But no changes, still crashes.  Did I some how delete the entire record and it no longer exists?

What I want to do is load everything onto the app, then delete all the objects in CoreData, so that when the app closes (or terminates) it saves all the new data in the records. Am I doing this correctly, or is there a much easier way to do this?  Oh yea, and I only have one entity that holds 5 NSStrings, so nothing to complicated.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. A high level description of your data model, the line on which the error occurs and the actual error you're getting would be really helpful.

Comment: I just one one Entity in my model. Called Movies. That entity has 5 attributes that are NSString's. Everything saves perfectly if all I do is save. It fetches with no problems. The problem only happens when I try to go delete objects then save later. It crashes when it saves and gives the SIGABRT on main application.

Comment: This code will erase all the `MOVIE_LIST` objects from the persistent store along with all their data. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Yes.  Christophers answer worked, but I also found out that my simulator was bad and needed to be re-installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, when you call the save method, there might be some mixup with some variable such as the `managedObjectContext`.

Did you try saving right after the deletion (i.e. in your `deleteStoredData` method above)?

BTW, I would also go with Christopher's code;-).

Comment: I change my code to what Christopher suggested, but it didn't help.  And yes, I tried saving after the deletion.  That's when it happens. If I don't delete anything, I can save all day.  But as soon as I try deleting even one object, the program crashes, giving me that **SIGABRT** error.

Comment: Perhaps your persistent store is broken? Try resetting the simulator.

Comment: Okay, looks like that's it.  The simulator is the one going cookoo.  I loaded the app on the phone, and it works perfectly.  Now I just gotta figure out why it loads fault.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting managed objects with a for loop like that is error prone and probably corrupting your  managedObjectContext. Try the following:

```
NSFetchRequest * fetch = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:MOVIE_LIST inManagedObjectContext:context]];

NSArray * result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];

for (NSManagedObject * event in result) {
    [context deleteObject:event];
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but same problem.  This is driving me nuts...lol.

Comment: This helped reduced errors, but i found my problem was that the simulator needed to be reset and re-installed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already have all of managedObject in your array, you do NOT need to do another fetch, just delete them with the code below should be OK.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.listOfMovies count] - 1; i++) {
    NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [self.listOfMovies objectAtIndex:i];
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];
}
```

If it still have problem, would you please tell me how many managedObjectContext do you have in your App? Are you deleting or saving it in a background thread?

In addition, would you please also post the crash log and the information by type "`bt` -> enter key" in console after your App crashed?